# Are there other non-printable characters in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, delimiter, ssis

From within SSIS, {t}, {CR}, {LF}, and {CR}{LF} are listed in the dropdown of row and column delimiters. I was wondering if there are other nomenclatures using the braces notation for non-printable characters? I've tried the following without success:

{bell} - bell
{b} - backspace
{^^} - column delimiter control character

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the flat file import task is pretty limited.  You could write your own script task or try to find another task.

Here is a list of add-ons for SSIS in codeplex:

http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/

A few catch my eye you should look at:

Regular Expression Flat File Source - A regular expression based flat file parsing source.

Delimited File Reader Source - A source component capable of parsing delimited flat files, including files with rows that are missing column fields.

Delimited File Source - An extremely robust flat file source for Integration Services which handles quoted text and provides full data auditing. Based on the work of Microsoft's Bob Bojanic (Delimited File Reader Source Sample).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this for sure, but given the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server) of bcp about row and field terminators, escpecially that only \t, \n, \r, \, \0 are the only supported non-printable characters I suspect maybe {TAB}/{NULL} are implemented but given they are not in de combobox they're probably not available.